# For some reason, my images don't have lined up links

Tags: html, css, position

I could be missing some coding, but here is what I mean:

[Messed up one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9dPS.png)

[Perfectly fine one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuDVo.png)

Basically, on the messed up web page, my links don't align like the other pages. My coding for the **MESSED UP ONE** is:

```
<div class="header"><div style="margin-left:200px;"> <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <p><a href="index.html" id="firstlink"><img src="images/1st-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/1st-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/1st-link.jpg'" /></a>
  <a href="whatis.html" id="rollover"><img src="images/2nd-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/2nd-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/2nd-link.jpg'" /></a>
  <a href="why.html" id="rollover"><img src="images/3rd-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/3rd-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/3rd-link.jpg'" /></a>
  <a href="resources.html" id="rollover"><img src="images/4th-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/4th-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/4th-link.jpg'" /></a>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img id="image" src="images/14_Seal2.jpg" /> <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="main="Main" content="Content"" --><p id="main">Main Content</p>

<div id="footer"><p><form action="" method="post" id="form-radio">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Website Feedback" value="radio" id="WebsiteFeedback_0" />
      Yes</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Website Feedback" value="radio" id="WebsiteFeedback_1" />
      No</label>
    <br />
  </p>
</form></p><p id="pfoot" style="vertical-align:bottom;">Teenspace and Teens For Antartica Preservation Inc. <br />Web Desinger: Mathew Crogan</p></div>
```

The coding for the **PERFECTLY FINE** page is:

```
<div class="header"><div style="margin-left:200px;"> <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
</div>
<div>
  <p><a href="index.html" id="firstlink"><img src="images/1st-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/1st-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/1st-link.jpg'" /></a>
  <a href="whatis.html" id="rollover"><img src="images/2nd-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/2nd-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/2nd-link.jpg'" /></a>
  <a href="why.html" id="rollover"><img src="images/3rd-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/3rd-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/3rd-link.jpg'" /></a>
  <a href="resources.html" id="rollover"><img src="images/4th-link.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/4th-link-roll.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/4th-link.jpg'" /></a>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img src="images/14_Teens.jpg" id="image"/><!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="main="Main" content="Content"" --><p id="main">Main Content</p>

<div id="footer"><p id="pfoot" style="vertical-align:bottom;">Teenspace and Teens For Antartica Preservation Inc. <br />Web Desinger: Mathew Crogan</p></div>
```

And lastly, the **CSS STYLE SHEET** for **BOTH** pages is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.header
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

html
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color:#D7D7FF;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}


    #rollover
{
display:block;
width:120px;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
margin-top:30px;
}

#firstlink
{
    display:block;
width:120px;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
margin-top:30px;
margin-left:265px;
}

a img
{
    border:none;
}

#image
{
    height:230px; 
    width:300px; 
    float:left; 
    border: 3px solid #B5B5B5; 
    margin-left:150px; 
    margin-top:10px;
    border-radius:25px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 6px #A3A3A3;

}


#main
{
    height:250px; 
    width:450px; 
    border:3px solid #B5B5B5; 
    margin-left:500px; 
    margin-top:15px;
    border-radius:25px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 6px #A3A3A3;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight:400;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#footer
{
    height:100px;
    bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-left:25px;
}

#pfoot
{
    margin-left:50px;
}

#form-radio
{
    float:left;
}
```

Any help would be **MUCH** appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Which images exactly? In the bottom? The menu? both pages look hideous and the HTML is a complete mess. All those `<p>&nbsp;</p>` tags would be better done with a single `margin-bottom: 30px;` or something similair, all you do now is stacking margins. Look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp to see what `<p>` is actually for.

Comment: Do you mean 1 menu is higher?

Comment: Yea I know both are hideous, my teacher is FORCING me to use Dreamweaver rather then actually type out the code on my own, which makes unnecessary coding and the website will of course look terrible because It's a school project that I have no control over which coding I put into it. And yes, I do mean 1 menu is higher then the other

Comment: well the messed up one has a extra closing `</div>` after the `<div class="header">`

Comment: Alright, I'll see if that well get it to work.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct or not cause there are 2x `<div>` in front which is correct, so if it's the entire page the "messed up" is actually the correct one. Is this the actual entire page? The correct one might only look better cause your browser adds another closing `</div>` somewhere else. But look how little HTML you actually need to make something similair; http://jsfiddle.net/7UvZM/

DreamWeaver has a code mode, remove the `<p>`s and add margins? Count the `<divs>` and open+close properly.

Comment: Actually, I attempted to remove that extra `</div>` in the top part of the page like you suggested, worked like a charm. Believe me by the way when I say I do know coding and actually have experience with it, and I understand how little html is actually needed. But my Web Design teacher forces me to use Dreamweaver (Which is absolutely terrible) so I am just going through the motions rather then making a site how I prefer